# Conditions in reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Is it a **bad** idea to use conditions in reducers? Something like this:

```
case types.SET_SOME_ACTION:
   if(typeof someElement !== "undefined") {
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
          someElement: action.value
       })
    }
```

Trying to see if this is an anti-pattern. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it is a general consensus to put your business logic in an action creator. That leaves reducers with only one responsibility: to update the state.

See this discussion for more: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1165

The redux FAQ also recommends a dumb reducer: http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/CodeStructure.html#how-should-i-split-my-logic-between-reducers-and-action-creators-where-should-my-business-logic-go

Personally, I only do simple validation in the redux store, the actual business logic is handled by Redux Observable or Redux Thunk.

Comment: I completely agree with your answer. However, I'm dealing with an interesting scenario and so far the only solution I've come up with is to use a condition in a reducer -- which I do NOT want to do. Here's that scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45874594/handling-one-property-effecting-the-state-of-another

Comment: The FAQ might have recommended putting as little logic as possible in de reducer in 2017, but it now recommends doing the opposite: Put as much logic in the reducer as possible because it "helps ensure that more of the actual app logic is easily testable, enables more effective use of time-travel debugging, and helps avoid common mistakes that can lead to mutations and bugs". Also see https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#put-as-much-logic-as-possible-in-reducers