# Can I use condition in my action reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Basically, in our case, we need to either get an alerts list that shows the first few items (mounting it first time in the DOM) or show the initial list + the next list (clicking a `load more` button).

Hence we needed to do this condition in our `GET_ALERTS` action:

```
case "GET_ALERTS":
    if (action.initialList) {
        newState.list = [...newState.list, action.res.data.list];
    } else {
        newState.list = newState.list.concat(
            action.res.data.list
        );
    }
```

And when we call the action reducer in our Alerts component, we need to indicate whether `initialList` is true or false.

E.g.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getAlerts(pageNum, true);
}

markAllAsRead() {
   // other code calling api to mark all as read
   this.props.getAlerts(pageNum, false);
}

readMore() {
  // other code that increases pageNum state counter
  this.props.getAlerts(pageNum, true);
}
```

Anyway in such a case, is it fine to use conditional statement in the reducer?

Comment: You could consider using [getState()](https://redux.js.org/api/store) in your action creator to conditionally create the appropriate payload before dispatching to the reducer to avoid conditional logic in your reducer.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45874393/conditions-in-reducers

Answer (score 5):

I am against this idea. The reducer has a single responsibility: update Redux state according to the action.

Here are three ways to slove this:

### easy way - initialize your list in Redux state to empty list

if you set the list in `state` to empty list (`[]`) then it's much simpler.
You can basically just change your reducer to this:

```
case "GET_ALERTS":
    return {...state, list: [...state.list, action.res.data.list]
```

This will make sure that even if you have get initial list or more items to add to the list, they will be appended. No need to add any logic - which is awesome IMHO.

### redux-thunk and separating type into two different types

create two actions: `GET_INIT_ALERTS` and `GET_MORE_ALERTS`.

```
switch(action.type) {
case "GET_INIT_ALERTS":
    return {...state, list: action.res.data.list }
case "GET_MORE_ALERTS":
    return {...state, list: [...state.list, ...action.res.data.list]}
case "CHECK_READ_ALERTS":
    return {...state, read: [...state.read, ...action.res.data.list]}
}
```

In the component I will have:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getInitAlerts();
}

markAllAsRead() {
   // other code calling api to mark all as read
   this.props.getAlerts(pageNum, false);
}

readMore() {
  // other code that increases pageNum state counter
  this.props.getAlerts(pageNum);
}
```

In alerts action with the help of redux-thunk:

```
export const getAlerts = (pageNum : number) => (dispatch) => {
    return apiAction(`/alerts/${pageNum}`, 'GET').then(res => dispatch({type: "GET_MORE_ALERTS", res});
}

export const getInitAlerts = () => (dispatch) => {
    return apiAction('/alerts/1', 'GET').then(res => dispatch({type: "GET_INIT_ALERTS", res});
}
```

I guess you update `pageNum` after `readMore` or `componentDidMount`. Of course you can save that state in Redux and map it back to props and just increment it when calling the `getAlerts` action.

### write your own middleware

Another way to do this is to write an ad-hoc/feature middleware to `concat` new data to a list.

```
const concatLists = store => next => action => {
    let newAction = action
    if (action.type.includes("GET") && action.initialList) {
       newAction = {...action, concatList: action.res.data.list}
    } else if (action.type.includes("GET") {
       newAction = {...action, concatList: [...state[action.key].list, action.res.data.list]}
    }
    return next(newAction);
}
```

And change your reducer to simply push `concatList` to the state:

```
case "GET_ALERTS":
    return {...state, list: action.concatList}
```

In addition, you will have to change your action to include `key` (in this case the key will be set to `alert` (or the name of the key where you store the alert state in redux) and initialList to determine whether to concat or not.

BTW, it's a good practice to put these two under the `meta` key.

```
{
  type: "GET_ALERT",
  meta: {
    initialList: true,
    key: "alert",
  },
  res: {...}
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Oops maybe I haven't told the whole story. For first solution, we cannot do so because when user clicks on "Mark All as Read", 3 things happen: 1.) reset the alert list in the store to [ ], 2.) a separate API endpoint is called to mark all as read, 3.) get the alert list again which will now show that they are all read. If we don't do the reset, the new list (from #3 will just append to the end of the old list instead of replacing it). This is fine, however, doing the reset will briefly show the preloader before repopulating which is not instantaneous. So we had to do the condition as above.

Comment: For number 2 solution, I was also thinking that but I don't know which is better, to have 2 separate action creators doing almost the same GET request (just with different params) or just do the condition in the reducer. I thought the second one was sort of more DRY and lesser code.. But yeah, we can consider that.. For number 3 solution, am quite new to redux so may need to read up more on that.. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to have following set of actions:

- ALERTS/INIT - loads initial list
- ALERTS/LOAD_MORE - loads next page and then increments pageNo, so next call will know how many pages are loaded
- ALERTS/MARK_ALL_AS_READ - does server call and reinitializes list

The store structure

```
{
    list: [],
    currentPage: 0
}
```

And component code should not track pageNum

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.initAlerts();
}

markAllAsRead() {
   this.props.markAllAsRead();
}

readMore() {
   this.props.loadMore();
}
```